# JavaScript inheritance through a call to the ancestor function

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am experimenting with (for me) a new type of inheritance. I would like to call the inherited function with an argument which determines which inheritor object is returned.

Here is an example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
function Localizor(type) {
  this.language = "English"
  this.endonym = "English"

  if (window[type]) {
    return new window[type]()
  }
}
Localizor.prototype.native = function native() {
  return "I speak " + this.endonym
}
Localizor.prototype.english = function () {
  return "I speak " + this.language
}


function French () {
  this.language = "French";  
  this.endonym = "français"
}
French.prototype = new Localizor()
French.prototype.native = function french() {
  return "Je parle " + this.endonym
}


function Thai () {
  this.language = "Thai";  
  this.endonym = "ไทย"
}
Thai.prototype = new Localizor()
Thai.prototype.native = function thai() {
  return "พูดภาษา" + this.endonym
}
```

If I call `new Localizor()` with no argument (or with an invalid argument), I get a plain English object. If I call it with an argument of "French" or "Thai", I get an object where the inheritor overwrites some of the inherited methods, so that it speaks French or Thai. For example:

```
var thai = new Localizor("Thai")
var feedback = thai.language + " | " + thai.endonym + " | " + thai.english() + " | " + thai.native()  
console.log(feedback)
```

This gives me the output `Thai | ไทย | I speak Thai | พูดภาษาไทย`.

I have three questions:
1. Is this type of inheritance already documented somewhere (does it have a name)?
2. Are there any dangers in working this way?
3. This example checks on the existence of `window[type]`, which is good when working in a browser. If this were in a module in node.js, is there an equivalent way of determining if a function exists within the module?

### Edit in response to Zero21xxx

Here's one way that I have found of detecting the existence of constructors in a module, but it looks dangerously incestuous to me. What risks does it have? What better approaches are available?

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype = Parent.prototype
  Child.prototype = new F()
  //Child.prototype.constructor = Child
  Child.parent = Parent.prototype
}

function Localizor(type) {
  this.language = "English"
  this.endonym = "English"

  this.French = function français () {
    this.language = "French";  
    this.endonym = "français"
  }
  extend(this.French, this)
  this.French.prototype.native = function french() {
    return "Je parle " + this.endonym
  }

  this.Thai = function ไทย () {
    this.language = "Thai";  
    this.endonym = "ไทย"
  }
  extend(this.Thai, this)
  this.Thai.prototype.native = function thai() {
    return "พูดภาษา" + this.endonym
  }

  if (typeof this[type] === "function") {
   return new this[type]()
  }
}
Localizor.prototype.native = function native() {
  return "I speak " + this.endonym
}
Localizor.prototype.english = function () {
  return "I speak " + this.language
}

module.exports = Localizor
```

Comment: Seems like a good use case for a factory pattern. `Localizer.create('French')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my humble opinion you should have three separate constructors for `English`, `French` and `Thai` which inherit from a common constructor (let's call it `Locale`). It would look as follows:

```
function Locale(constructor, language, endonym, native) {
    this.constructor = constructor;
    this.language = language;
    this.endonym = endonym;

    this.native = function () {
        return native + this.endonym;
    };
}

Locale.prototype.english = function () {
    return "I speak " + this.language;
};

function English() {}
function French() {}
function Thai() {}

English.prototype = new Locale(English, "English", "English", "I speak ");
French.prototype = new Locale(French, "French", "français", "Je parle ");
Thai.prototype = new Locale(Thai, "Thai", "ไทย", "พูดภาษา");
```

This leads to [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): each constructor only does precisely what it's intended for. Nothing more, nothing less. Now you could create a `localizer` function as follows:

```
function localizer(language) {
    switch (language) {
    case "French": return new French;
    case "Thai": return new Thai;
    default: return new English;
    }
}
```

Hence all you need to do is call `localizer` to get the desired `Locale`.

Comment: This makes good sense, thank you. (I can't vote up your answer yet, because I haven't got enough reputation :) The 'this.constructor = constructor' technique is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yeah this is the "pseudo-classical" kind of inheritance that people often try to achieve with varying degrees of success. Check out [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/pseudo-classical-pattern)
2. Well the way you have it now is a little hard to read. The code you write says create a `Localizor` object, but you are handed back a `Thai` object. That could get very hard to trace for errors.
3. Yes there are ways for checking such things, it really depends on how you construct the module.

My suggestion would be to rewrite this slightly like this

```
function Localizor(language, endonym) {
  this.language = language;
  this.endonym = endonym;
}
Localizor.prototype.native = function native() {
  return "I speak " + this.endonym;
};
Localizor.prototype.english = function () {
  return "I speak " + this.language;
};


function French (language, endonym) {
  Localizor.apply(this, arguments);
}
French.prototype = new Localizor();
French.prototype.native = function french() {
  return "Je parle " + this.endonym;
};


function Thai (language, endonym) {
  Localizor.apply(this, arguments);
}
Thai.prototype = new Localizor();
Thai.prototype.native = function thai() {
  return "พูดภาษา" + this.endonym;
};
```

That way, you can invoke the correct constructor and get the corresponding object back. You can also call the "base class" constructor and attach the `language` and `endonym` properties without having to copy and paste that code. You also wouldn't need to check types like you are currently doing since you are declaring them how you want them to function. Finally if you wanted, you could have your `Localizor` function take a third parameter and that would be the string "I Speak" or whatever and then you wouldn't event need more than one object.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/UVOpiNo/1/edit) is a playground you can mess with.

Server or client side, I think this is a better approach.

Comment: Many thanks for your thoughtful input.

I (believe I) understand pseudo-classical inheritance, but what I am attempting is something different, perhaps closer to parasitic inheritance but with the option of choosing the parasite.

I want to avoid invoking Thai or French directly, so that I can use a string variable to indicate which object I want to get back, depending on third-party input.

As for question 3, can you suggest one way to construct the module so that I can check for the existence of a given constructor?